# Delphi Virtual Listview does not work properly

Tags: listview, delphi, virtual

I have a simple test program, in which I try to get a Virtual Listview to work.
But it won't work properly, because when the TListview OwnerData is enabled, the OnChange no longer is called when a group of Items in UN-selected.
As a result, I end up with a larger and larger group of Virtual Items, which are marked as Selected, but they have been un-selected in the ListView itself.

However, in the second ListView which is NOT in Ownerdata, all UnSelect items cause an OnChange, as would be expected.

I have been working on it for days, but I cannot make it work.
It would be great if somebody would be prepared to have a look at it, and see what I may do wrong, as I really don't think the problem is with my own code...

The entire test program source can be downloaded here (200k):

https://sartrack.nz/temp/VirtualListViewTest.zip

Thanks, Bart

Comment: Isn't this as designed? I know that my virtual list views have no problems dealing with selection. I expect you just need to think differently about how it works.

Answer (score 1):

As David already mentioned, that is as designed. In virtual mode you need to wire the `OnSelectItem` event to get notified about the change of an items selection state.

In case you allow multi selection in the view, the `OnSelectItem` is not sufficient and the `OnDataStateChange` has to be wired, too. It is then mandatory to use both events, as each covers only a subset of use cases.

Comment: I will update my question with more details.

Comment: Now I suddenly cannot edit my own question.

Comment: OnSelectItem is NOT reporting on many Items which are US-Selected.  As I can no longer edit my question, please read the actual LOG results step-by-step here. This shows exactly what happens. As does the source code I uploaded.  https://sartrack.nz/temp/VirtualListView1.txt  .. Just a short text file.